# Strange behaviour of BitBlt for a second monitor that is not being set as primary

Tags: windows, gdi, screen-capture, bitblt, stretchblt

I capture images using BitBlt / StretchBlt API's on windows 10, depending upon the necessity for scaling the screen or not. Whenever I capture the 2nd  monitor that is not being configured as primary, there seems to be a strange behaviour that the captured screen's first half is the replica of the second half of the screen. This occurs randomly once for every 10 images on an average.

I could not find any documents over the internet related to this kind of strange problems. I'm not even doing any multi-threading. Might there be a problem with the capturing frequency?, But that doesn't even look sense, as there is no issue with screen capture whenever I set the monitor as primary.

Here is the original image

[image: Original image]

captured image

[image: Captured image]

monitor alignment

[image: Monitor alignment]

**Note:** *I have been able to reproduce the issue only when the forground window is Notepad++ as of now. I'm not sure whether the issue happens for other applications as well.*, I could not go for directX based approach as the program must run on WindowsXP as well.

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC ( hDC ) ;

HBITMAP previousImage = ( HBITMAP ) SelectObject ( memDC , curImage ) 

if ( ( previousImage ) == NULL )
{
    return -1;
}

BOOL blitok ;

if ( lf_ImageScalingFactor != (double)1.0 )
{
    SetStretchBltMode ( memDC , HALFTONE ) ;

    if ( capture_all )
    {
        blitok = StretchBlt ( memDC , 0 , 0 , (int)(clientwindow.Width () ) , (int) (clientwindow.Height () ), 
            hDC , clientwindow.left - (physicalscreenrect.left * lf_ImageScalingFactor), clientwindow.top - (physicalscreenrect.top * lf_ImageScalingFactor), physicalscreenrect.Width(), physicalscreenrect.Height(), SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        blitok = StretchBlt ( memDC , 0 , 0 , (int)(clientwindow.Width ()) , (int)(clientwindow.Height ()), 
                hDC , clientwindow.left - (physicalscreenrect.left * lf_ImageScalingFactor), clientwindow.top - (physicalscreenrect.top * lf_ImageScalingFactor),physicalscreenrect.Width(), physicalscreenrect.Height(), SRCCOPY ) ;
    }
}
else
{
    if ( capture_all )
    {
        blitok = BitBlt ( memDC , 0 , 0 , clientwindow.Width (), clientwindow.Height (), 
                hDC , clientwindow.left - physicalscreenrect.left , clientwindow.top - physicalscreenrect.top , SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        blitok = BitBlt ( memDC , 0 , 0 , clientwindow.Width (), clientwindow.Height (), 
                hDC , clientwindow.left - physicalscreenrect.left , clientwindow.top - physicalscreenrect.top , SRCCOPY ) ;
    }

}

SelectObject ( memDC , previousImage ) ;

DeleteDC ( memDC ) ;
DeleteDC ( hDC ) ;
```

Am I doing something wrong over here?.

Any help is appreciable, Thanks in advance.

Comment: DPI-awareness is the usual problem, especially so on Win10 since its installer no longer picks 96 dpi as the default.  Well, you have it at 150% (aka 144 dpi) so if you don't include dpiAware in the manifest then you'll be lied to about the position and size of other windows.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant your suggestion was really useful, I checked the dpi of the 2 monitors and they are different.The problem is gone when I set the same dpi for both of them. I did not understand what is happening though I had set the per monitor dpi awareness to true.

Comment: Per-monitor DPI awareness is an issue in Windows versions >= 8.1.  Requires a different value in the manifest.  Googles well.

Comment: You mean   <dpiAware>true/PM</dpiAware> would not work properly on win 8.1 and greater?

Comment: @Hans Passant just for the clarification, it looks like the DPI awareness works fine, I tried with and without DPI awareness for whole system as well as per-monitor DPI setting. Otherwise it couldn't have captured other windows perfectly without any problems, I see the issue occurs only when I move the mouse over the particular notepad++ window and that too in a random manner. As it is not in full screen and I could see the other windows being captured properly.

Comment: Whenever I run my application with admin privileges with the same DPI & Monitor settings, that issue is gone. I don't understand what is happening.